# MPAndroidChart - BarChart on xaxis geting postion instead of values

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I was trying MPAndroidChart for a basic bar chart. I am facing issue with Xaxis.

Here is my code to set Xaxis :

protected List weeks =new ArrayList() ;

```
                    weeks.add("jan");
                    weeks.add("feb");
                    weeks.add("mar");
                    weeks.add("apr");
                    weeks.add("may");
                    weeks.add("jun");                   


                    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
                    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                    xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    xAxis.setValues(weeks);
```

But in xaxis I am geting postion i.e. 0 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 instead of months name.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the x-axis labels for the data object you are using and **not set them directly** to the axis.

E.g.

```
LineData data = new LineData(xValues, dataSets);
```

For more details, read the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data).

Comment: Thanks Jahoda, This was of great help, put me into right direction. Cheers!